# How to get marathi data from web service which is in .net to spinner?

Tags: android, json, json.net

I am trying it for just another text with yesterdays answers

[Just taken one text view and in on create only tried to apply custom font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf77q.png)

And  the output still not getting [Output is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpM1l.png)

current output

[image]

See code below

[image]

Its showing like this in emulator

```
{"Get_DepoScheme": [{
            "Flag": 1,
            "Msg": "Success",
            "SchemeId": 1,
            "SchemeName": "मुदत ठेव",
            "Glid": 55
        }, {
            "Flag": 1,
            "Msg": "Success",
            "SchemeId": 2,
            "SchemeName": "कर्मचारी भ.नि.नि.मुदत ठेव",
            "Glid": 38
        }, {
            "Flag": 1,
            "Msg": "Success",
            "SchemeId": 3,
            "SchemeName": "सभासद कायम ठेव",
            "Glid": 14
        }, {
            "Flag": 1,
            "Msg": "Success",
            "SchemeId": 5,
            "SchemeName": "आवर्ती ठेव (आर.डी.)",
            "Glid": 51
        }, {
            "Flag": 1,
            "Msg": "Success",
            "SchemeId": 6,
            "SchemeName": "सुकन्या ठेव योजना",
            "Glid": 77
        }, {
            "Flag": 1,
            "Msg": "Success",
            "SchemeId": 7,
            "SchemeName": "स्वामी पेन्शन ठेव योजना",
            "Glid": 78
        }, {
            "Flag": 1,
            "Msg": "Success",
            "SchemeId": 16,
            "SchemeName": "दामदुप्पट ठेव",
            "Glid": 54
        }]
    }
```

Comment: share your code so far

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode  Please also add whatever error you are receiving so that we can help you solve the issue.

Comment: added image of code and displaying output in emulator in diff language

Comment: @Angel your question is rather unclear, and it would be much easier if you provided your code in text and added any errors/stack-traces as well. Are you having an issue with the data being in Marathi ? or are you having some other issue ?

Comment: @casualcoder , i added image which is displaying my output, my question is that , how it will be display in marathi coz its displaying in some other language

Comment: @Angel you might need to change the encoding of you strings to unicode (UTF-8) to support the Devanagari script. what your seeing is not another language but a bad representation of the letters due to a mismatched encoding

Answer (score 0):

try `URLDecoder`, for example try this

```
String flag = URLDecoder.decode(json_data.getString("Flag"), "UTF-8");
```

and set the text to textview like this

```
     TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
     Typeface marathi = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "akshar.ttf");
     tv.setTypeface(marathi);
     tv.setText(flag);
```

Download the **marathi** font from [here](http://marathi.changathi.com/Fonts.aspx) and create an asset folder in your project and add it there.(assets location `app>src>main>assets>akshar.ttf`)

**output ->>**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for ur answer but still it displaying as it is there is no change in output

Comment: @Angel you will need to add font to your asset folder, see updated answer

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made

Comment: the font file may be corrupt try this one http://fonts.webtoolhub.com/font-n20162-shivaji01.aspx

Comment: search for marathi `ttf` file and try adding it

Comment: I alreay tried for different fonts ,still getting same error

Comment: @Angel i found the issue-> `java.lang.RuntimeException: native typeface cannot be made` this error occurs when you have not added `akshar.ttf` properly in assets folder. The correct path is `app>src>main>assets>akshar.ttf`

Comment: @Angel if path is correct,  just reinstall the app it should work, see the screenshot attached in answer

Comment: Now not getting exception after changing assets folder path but output showing same not in marathi

Comment: Typeface marathi = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "akshar.ttf");      tv.setTypeface(marathi); this should be done in oncreate

Comment: I just tried this things , updated my question , still not showing it properly , also tried for some diff fonts

Comment: `akshar.ttf` provided in the link in my answer is working, i have tested it myself , double click the `akshar.ttf` file in android studio to check its contents

Comment: Yes, its working with akshar.ttf , But that my json data is coming in another format so typeface not working there,in webservice m getting that data in marathi while m parsing json data in android that results like :- { "Get_DepoScheme": [{"Flag":1,"Msg":"Success","SchemeId":1,"SchemeName":"à¤®à¥à¤¦à¤¤ à¤ à¥à¤µ","Glid":55},{"Flag":1,"Msg":"Success","SchemeId":2,"SchemeName":"à¤à¤°à¥à¤®à¤à¤¾à¤°à¥ à¤­.à¤¨à¤¿.à¤¨à¤¿.à¤®à¥à¤¦à¤¤ à¤ à¥à¤µ","Glid":38}]} , this is not converting

Comment: is the response coming correctly in postman/or any other tools

Comment: @Angel if the response itself is like this, then you will need a backend fix for this

Answer (score 0):

used AsyncTask :

```
public class TestMarathiData extends ActionBarActivity
{
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = null,Uname;
    String line = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList list1;
    boolean isInternetConn;
    Button btn1;
    TelephonyManager tel;
    String IMEI;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog ;
    String GetSchemePath="URL here";

   HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection ;
    URL url;
    OutputStream outputStream;
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter ;
    int RC ;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader ;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder;
    boolean check = true;
    TextView txtv_scheme;
    Spinner SpinnerScheme;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_marathi_data);
        ///// HTTP code ////
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        //
        /////// to get IMEI number ///////
        tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        IMEI = tel.getDeviceId().toString();
        //
        //Global Variables
        final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
        //

       Uname = globalVariable.getUID();

        list1=new ArrayList<String>();
        txtv_scheme = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtv_scheme);
        btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        SpinnerScheme = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerScheme);

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                GetDepositScheme();
            }
        });
    }//EOF OnCreate
    //GetDepositScheme
    private void GetDepositScheme()
    {
        class AsyncTaskGetScheme extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
        {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(TestMarathiData.this,"Fetching Data","Please Wait",false,false);
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String string1)
            {
                super.onPostExecute(string1);
                try
                {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("Get_DepoScheme");
                    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String SchemeId = json_data.getString("SchemeId");
                        String SchemeName = json_data.getString("SchemeName");
                        //
                        l.add(SchemeId+"-"+SchemeName);
                        //
                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TestMarathiData.this,R.layout.spinner_item,l)
                        {
                                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                                {
                                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                                    Typeface externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF");
                                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);
                                    return v;
                                }
                            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                            {
                                    View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                                    Typeface externalFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/akshar.ttf");
                                    ((TextView) v).setTypeface(externalFont);
                                    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                                    return v;
                                }
                            };
                            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        SpinnerScheme.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }  // for
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    SpinnerScheme.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
                        {
                            String Spinner_item = SpinnerScheme.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected :: " + Spinner_item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0)
                        {}
                    });//
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                GetSchemeClass getschemeClass = new GetSchemeClass();
                HashMap<String,String> HashMapParams = new HashMap<String,String>();
                HashMapParams.put("Username",Uname);

               String FinalData = getschemeClass.GetSchemeHttpRequest(GetSchemePath,HashMapParams);
                return FinalData;
            }
        }
        AsyncTaskGetScheme AsyncTaskGetSchemeOBJ = new AsyncTaskGetScheme();
        AsyncTaskGetSchemeOBJ.execute();
    }//EOF GetDepositScheme
    //GetSchemeClass
    private class GetSchemeClass
    {
        public String GetSchemeHttpRequest(String requestURL, HashMap<String, String> PData)
        {
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            try
            {
                url = new URL(requestURL);
                httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setReadTimeout(20000);
                httpURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(20000);
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                bufferedWriter.write(bufferedWriterDataFN(PData));
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                RC = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                if (RC == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String RC2;
                    while ((RC2 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        stringBuilder.append(RC2);
                    }
                }
                result = stringBuilder.toString();
                Log.d("Result", "Result" + result);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        private String bufferedWriterDataFN(HashMap<String, String> HashMapParams) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
        {
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> KEY : HashMapParams.entrySet())
            {
                if (check)
                    check = false;
                else
                    stringBuilder.append("&");
                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                stringBuilder.append("=");
                stringBuilder.append(URLEncoder.encode(KEY.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }//EOF GetSchemeClass
}//EOF Main
```